# While loop iterating one too many times

Tags: python, while-loop, iteration

I have four input statements that create a simple calculation. I want the user to be able to type 0 in the first prompt in order to stop the program immediately, but the program takes the user through the entire loop before stopping. How do I make it so the program stops iterating directly after typing a command like 0?

```
def main():
      input_1 = 1
      input_2 = 1
      input_3 = 1
      input_4 = 1
      while input_1 !=0:
           input_1 = int(input('Please enter a value or type 0 to end: '))
           input_2 = int(input('Please enter a second value: '))
           input_3 = int(input('Please enter a third value: '))
           input_4 = int(input('Please enter a fourth value: '))
           print('The total amount is: ', end='')      
           print(all_inputs(input_1,input_1,input_1,input_1), end='')


def all_inputs(first,second,third,fourth):
     sum = first + second + third + fourth
     return(sum)
main()
```

Comment: `break` from the loop, or use a `do...while` loop instead.

Comment: I cant see any problem, when I run your code, please give `0` in first argument, and it should work fine

Comment: @Nilesh the poster wants the loop to terminate immediately if the input is 0 instead of running through all the questions.

Comment: @KieranE I got the point when I read it again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either exit on input_1 == 0 or wrap everything after input_1 in a if to execute only when input_1 !=0.

```
def main():
  input_1 = 1
  input_2 = 1
  input_3 = 1
  input_4 = 1
  while input_1 !=0:
       input_1 = int(input('Please enter a value or type 0 to end: '))
       if input_1 != 0 :
           input_2 = int(input('Please enter a second value: '))
           input_3 = int(input('Please enter a third value: '))
           input_4 = int(input('Please enter a fourth value: '))
           print('The total amount is: ', end='')      
           print(all_inputs(input_1,input_1,input_1,input_1), end='')


def all_inputs(first,second,third,fourth):
 sum = first + second + third + fourth
 return(sum)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

While @FredMan is correct, I feel as if you could really tidy up your loop.  I'm not a Python guy, but here's what I came up with:

```
def main():
      keep_going = '';
      while keep_going != 'n':
           input_1 = int(input('Please enter a value: '))
           input_2 = int(input('Please enter a second value: '))
           input_3 = int(input('Please enter a third value: '))
           input_4 = int(input('Please enter a fourth value: '))
           print('The total amount is: ', end='')
           # In your example, you sum input_1 four times
           # \n at the end adds a newline      
           print(all_inputs(input_1,input_2,input_3,input_4), end="\n")
           keep_going = input('Keep going? y/n: ')


def all_inputs(first,second,third,fourth):
     sum = first + second + third + fourth
     return(sum)
main()
```

There are many other ways to clean this up, but I felt this was an easy fix that keeps the style you were going for in mind :)

Edit:  Here's another way to go about it

```
def main():
  keep_going = '';
  while keep_going != 'n':
    answers = []
    answers.insert(0, input('Please enter a value: '))
    answers.insert(0, input('Please enter a second value: '))
    answers.insert(0, input('Please enter a third value: '))
    answers.insert(0, input('Please enter a fourth value: '))

    total = sum([*map(int, answers)])
    print("The total amount is: {}".format(total))      
    keep_going = input('Keep going? y/n: ')

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not a Python user as much but I see where your issue is.

The preset value for input_1, 2, 3 and four are done inside the loop.

Why Don't you take the input_1 outside the loop instead on inside the loop. That way as soon as you run the function it will go through the while look check if input_1 != 0 and if it is, the loop will terminate immediately.

In fact, why do you need a loop at all since you are already collecting the 4 arguments with four separate variables. You could just do this

```
def main:
    input_1 = int(input('Please enter first value: '))
    input_2 = int(input('Please enter a second value: '))
    input_3 = int(input('Please enter a third value: '))
    input_4 = int(input('Please enter a fourth value: '))
    print('The total amount is: ', end='')      
    print(all_inputs(input_1,input_2,input_3,input_4), end='')

def all_inputs(first,second,third,fourth):
    sum = first + second + third + fourth
    return(sum)

main()
```